# Match index two column criteria and one row criteria in google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

I have a data set where I want to create a search based on SKU and PO (two columns) and either online or store (one row).  Usually I can do a simple `index(match())` function with one criteria of each, but it becomes complicated when adding a second column to search.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(IF(F2=C1, C:C, D:D), A:A=G2, B:B=H2)
```